# PHP created watermark looks strange

Tags: php, watermark

I have script that add water mark (PNG, transparent) to image(JPG). Works fine with a catch - in some way water mark changes colors and makes it NOT transparent.
This is code i use for adding water mark:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('../../pics/'.$ran.'_large.jpg');
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 70);

// Save the image to file and free memory
imagejpeg($im, '../../pics/'.$ran.'_large.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
```

[Image with watermark after PHP generates it (wrong way)](http://i39.tinypic.com/20iuwk7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for help guys - [I found answer in this site](http://www.benholmen.com/blog/2008/12/adding-png-watermarks-to-jpegs-with-php/)

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('../../pics/'.$ran.'_large.jpg');
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');

imagealphablending($im, true);

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;

$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

$offset = 10;

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - imagesx($stamp) - $offset, imagesy($im) - imagesy($stamp) - $offset, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
// Save the image to file and free memory
imagejpeg($im, '../../pics/'.$ran.'_large.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output image format is jpeg. Jpeg does not support transaprency. Change your output format to png.

Also suggest you to use image magic. Gd is very primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget these functions when it comes to PNG images with alpha maps after creating it from PNG:

```
imagealphablending($stamp,false);
imagesavealpha($stamp,true);
```

See if it makes any difference?